# Spelling in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I have troubles enabling spell check in TeXstudio under Windows. I know that my question is quite localized but I need help.
TeXstudio is set UTF-8 encoding and I am writing in Bulgarian. I downloaded dictionary files from [here](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/bulgarian-dictionaries-%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8). They are encoded in ANSI and they are for OOo 3.0 and above. 
When I copy the files in TeXstudio dictionary folder and switch to Bulgarian in TeXstudio I get the following:

> Could not determine encoding.

I tried to change dictionary encoding to UTF-8 or to change end-of-line character to UNIX but nothing happens. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve the problem. I asked the same question in latex discussion page on sourceforge. The solution is quite simple. The aff starts with this line:

> SET microsoft-cp1251

I just had to replace it with this one:

> SET Windows-1251